# Formatting Postgres row_to_json response for query

Tags: ruby, postgresql, postgresql-json

I have the following Postgres query:

```
"SELECT \"responses\".\"index\", \"responses\".\"created_at\",
ROUND(AVG(\"responses\".\"numeric\")) AS numeric
FROM \"responses\"
WHERE \"responses\".\"time\" = '#{time}'
GROUP BY \"responses\".\"index\", \"responses\".\"created_at\""
```

I'm trying to output the response as json using `row_to_json`. I can use:

```
"select row_to_json(row)
from (
  SELECT \"responses\".\"index\", \"responses\".\"created_at\",
  ROUND(AVG(\"responses\".\"numeric\")) AS numeric
  FROM \"responses\"
  WHERE \"responses\".\"time\" = '#{time}'
  GROUP BY \"responses\".\"index\", \"responses\".\"created_at\"
) row"
```

Which will give me:

```
{"row_to_json"=>"{\"index\":1,\"created_at\":\"2014-07-12 03:51:00\",\"numeric\":3}"}
```

However I don't really want the response nested in the `row_to_json` hash. Is there a simple way to remove that so I just return:

```
"{\"index\":1,\"created_at\":\"2014-07-12 03:51:00\",\"numeric\":3}"
```

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't return json like that. You're probably looking at an artifact of your access language (PHP?) or abstraction layer (PDO?)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall Interesting. I'm using Ruby. I'll look into it more.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `array_to_json` and `array_agg` functions.

For example:

```
SELECT array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(row))) FROM ...
```

It will return a correct JSON array

References:

- http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql
- http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/05/27/avoid-rails-when-generating-json-responses-with-postgresql.html